# two tables with the same Auto Generated Id

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I Have two entities with the relations OneToMany/ManyToOne

**Teacher**

```
 @Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"password"})
public class Teacher extends ResourceSupport{

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private Long id;
        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "teacher")
        private List<Course> courses;

       @JsonCreator
        public Teacher(@JsonProperty("Username") String username
            ,@JsonProperty("Password") String password){

                 this.username = username;
                 this.password = password;
        }

         public List<Course> getCourses() {
              return courses;
        }

        public void setCourses(List<Course> courses) {
              this.courses = courses;
        }

        public String getUsername(){
             return username;
        }

        public String getPassword(){
             return password;
        }

        @Setter
        private String username;


        @Setter
        private String password;

       Teacher(){

        }

}
```

The Course Entity

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"teacher"})
public class Course {

    @Getter @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) @Id private Long identifier;
    @Getter @Setter @NotNull private String name;
    @Getter @Setter @NotNull private  String description;
    @Getter @Setter @ManyToOne private Teacher teacher;

    @JsonCreator
    public Course(@JsonProperty("Name") String name , @JsonProperty("Description") String description , @JsonProperty("Teacher")Teacher teacher){
        this.description = description;
        this.name = name;
        this.teacher= teacher;
    }


}
```

IF i create 2 Teachers Objects through Postman in a PostRequest and i get them  on the table with its particular id.

but when i create a course it doest start with the id 1 it takes the last teachers id and start from there.

**This is what i get**

```
     [
    {
        "courses": [
            {
                "identifier": 3,
                "name": "java",
                "description": "java basico"
            }
        ],
        "username": "teuddy",
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "http://localhost:8181/teachers/teuddy"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "courses": [],
        "username": "rafael",
        "links": [
            {
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "http://localhost:8181/teachers/rafael"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

the course id its not the first one its the thirds , why?

**H2 DATABASE**
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/haoUy.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use in both entities the @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) and @GeneratedValue which defaults to GenerationType.AUTO . That means that a ID Generator appropriate for the used DB is determined. In case of a H2 database that´s a global sequence. So all entities share this sequence for id generation.

There are other strategies but afaik IDENTITY is not supported by H2 and falls back to SEQUENCE also.

If it is important to you that the entities don´t share their ids you could try the TABLE strategy but I wouldn´t recommend that. (for more information read [Why-you-should-never-use-the-table-identifier-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/why-you-should-never-use-the-table-identifier-generator-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)